# Extract data from this HTML using regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract to data between `<table class="clubs"> .. </table>`
using this code:

```
preg_match('#\<table class\="clubs"\>(.*?)\</table\>#', $raw_data, $new_data);
```

My HTML markup:

but i get empty array! what's wrong? I believe everything is escaped correctly

Comment: Don't use a regex. Use a DOM parser instead.

Comment: I'd guess you need the whatever that option was to match across multiple lines. (Or, better yet, as @AmalMurali says, use a DOM parser)

Comment: The is one interesting post I read few hour back  about `html` and `regex` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @ElectricRouge: Please. That doesn't help the OP. I know it's cool and all, but that's not helpful. Stop linking to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that `.` doesn't match newlines. You can fix it by using the `s` modifier to make `.` match newlines as well.

The second problem is that you're using `////` while there should be only one `/`. You also have a lot of unnecessary escapes:

```
preg_match('#<table class="clubs">(.*?)</table>#s', $raw_data, $new_data);
```

Should work. [regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fS0oL3)

That said, you would be better off with a parser dedicated to parse HTML.